# What does 'failing' mean

Tags: meaning

What does 'failing' mean in

> If the --target-directory (-t) option is given, or **failing** that if the last file is a directory and the --no-target-directory (-T) option is not given, ln creates a link to each target file in the specified directory, using the targets’ names.

Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/293514/674

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic phrase you are wondering about is

> failing that
>   *failing a condition to be present*

which means

> without that condition being met
>   in case that doesn't happen
>
> We will catch the last train to get home, ***failing that*** we will have to spend the night here.
>   I hope to get into the school of my choice, ***failing that*** I have a safety school as a backup.

Your passage is saying if either the "--target-directory" or "-t" option is not used, but the last name on the argument list is a directory *and* the "--no-target-directory" option is not given (to override the use of a directory name), the Unix command ln will create multiple symbolic links.